# Managing fragments with bottom navigation bar

Tags: android, android-fragments

I face problem with changing fragment in my container. I have three navigation: `Home`, `Special offers`, `Profile`. In `Home` navigation it could be `fragment1_1` or `fragment2_2` depending on situation. My problem is getting showed fragment from my container. I try to get using `findFragmentById`, but when I in `Profile` navigation and try to go to `Home` my code do not `hide()` fragment from `Pofile`. I tried to see the logs and I see that it hides `Home` and shows `Home`. My code for navigation:

```
botNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        when(it.itemId){
            R.id.act_home -> {
                if (!it.isChecked){
                    val homeFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("Home")
                    activeFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container)
                    activeFragment?.let { hideFragment(it) }
                    showFragment(homeFragment!!)
                }
            }
            R.id.act_profile_info -> {
                if (!it.isChecked) {
                    activeFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container)
                    activeFragment?.let { hideFragment(it) }
                    showFragment(profileFragment)
                }
            }
            R.id.act_special_offer -> {
                if (!it.isChecked) {
                    activeFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container)
                    activeFragment?.let { hideFragment(it) }
                    showFragment(specialFragment)

                }
            }
        }
        return@setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
    }
```

So now I want to understand why it is acting so and how can I get shown fragment from `FrameLayout` container.
For adding fragments for my navigation I used `addFragment()` function.

Comment: add pic of what you are getting now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this. Working fine for me tested.

Call this bellow method whenever want to add and show previous existing fragment

```
 /**
 * Method for add and replace and set fragment if exist in stack
 */
fun setAndReplaceFragment(fragmentWantToAdd: Fragment, tag: String) {
    val manager = supportFragmentManager
    val fragmentFind = manager.findFragmentByTag(tag)
    if (fragmentFind != null) {
        val ft = manager.beginTransaction()
        ft.replace(R.id.mFrmContainer, fragmentFind, tag)
        ft.addToBackStack(tag)
        ft.commit()
    } else {
        val ft = manager.beginTransaction()
        ft.replace(R.id.mFrmContainer, fragmentWantToAdd, tag)
        ft.addToBackStack(tag)
        ft.commit()
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any difference between `show()` `hide()` and `replace()` functions?

Comment: By the way such code is creating instance of the fragment each time, what I am trying to avoid

Comment: No its not creating a new instance of the each fragment, it just replace one fragment to another fragment.

Comment: I used `replace()` method as you suggested, but can you answer why my code's behavior was like as I described?

Comment: If you want to know why your code not working proper then I need your both method code which is important.

showFragment()

hideFragment()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202773/discussion-between-ketan-and-asset-bekbossynov).

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one :

```
            //Fragment1 is your new fragment to be shown.
            Fragment fragment=new Fragment1();
            if (fragment != null) {
                FragmentTransaction ft=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                //frams is your backup fragment upon on your navigation/new black 
                fragment(thi will beshown if the Fragment1 is not working)
                ft.replace(R.id.frams, fragment);
                ft.commit();
```